# Criteria for a set to be interval

Tags: real-analysis

Why every infinite set need not be an interval?
If we take R then it is an infinite set but can't we write it as (-infinite, infinite)?

Comment: Is the set $\mathbb{Z}$ of all integers an interval?

Comment: An interval of $\Bbb R$ is a set that meets two conditions: 1) It has at least two points (numbers) 2) If $x$ and $y$ are in the interval and $z$ is a real number such that $x<z<y$ then $z$ is also in the interval.